# Redering glb file using babylon viewer in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, babylonjs

I tried installing babylonjs/viewer and @babylonjs/viewer. Both are not working.
The first viewer is throwing a namespace error. second one has the issue with the typescript version below 5.

Anyone rendered glb file using babylon viewer inside angular component?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Have you considered using model-viewer?

Comment: @Dlyx : Below is the code details 

`HTML: 
<babylon id="babylon-viewer" camera.behaviors.auto-rotate="0"></babylon>

Ts:

ngOnInit() {
    babylonViewer.viewerManager
      .getViewerPromiseById('babylon-viewer')
      .then(function (viewer) {
        viewer.onEngineInitObservable.add(function (scene) {
          viewer.loadModel({
            url:
              'https://sample.glb',
          });
        });
      });
  }`

Errors: 

node_modules/@babylonjs/core/Engines/engine.d.ts: Cannot find name 'NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback'

Big list of errors

Comment: [here](https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/missing-types-for-imageencodeoptions-offscreenrenderingcontextid-and-offscreenrenderingcontext/40709) might be the same problem as you are having. Have you considered updating your typescript version or using an older babylonjs version?